# Why does python only correctly import if I'm using -m flag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm currently very confused on how imports in python work exactly. Basically, I'm confused why starting a script as a module (with -m) changes the behaviour:
I have a two scripts in a folder Called Testing. One named Programm.py, the other named Test_Programm.py.

The first line in Test_Programm.py is: `from Testing.Programm import my_function`

Running Test_Programm.py from the parent folder of Testing with the command line `python -m Testing`. Test_Programm works as expected, it imports everything as expected. Running it from within the Testing folder with `python -m Test_Programm`  doesn't get the import. Running it from the parent folder as `python Testing\Test_Programm.py` doesn't work. It also dosen't work when running inside the Testing folder with `python Test_Programm.py`.

So why is this, how does python look for modules?

All testing was done using Python 3.8.0

Stack Traces:

`python Testing\Test_Programm.py` in the parent folder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Testing\Test_Programm.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Testing.Test_Programm import my_function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Testing'
```

`python Test_Programm.py` in the Testing folder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_Programm.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Test_Programm import my_function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Testing'
```

`python -m Test_Programm.py` in the Testing folder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\TestingTesting\src\Testing\Test_Programm.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Testing.Test_Programm import my_function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Testing'
```

Comment: Please include the full error traceback.

Comment: Done, added them at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the `sys.path` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), `path[0]` is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first.

And per [the Python command-line documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options):

> When called with `-m module-name`, the given module is located on the Python module path and executed as a script.

An implication of that second quote is that the `-m` invocation method is not "running a script" in the sense `sys.path` describes it, because it has to set up `sys.path` *first*, then look for the module to execute, so it can't be making `path[0]` match the script directory (`sys.path` is generally not programmatically modified by Python itself after initial setup by the interpreter, followed by the `site` module).

Between the two of them, this answers your question. Since your directories are not part of the "always on" `sys.path`, you're relying on the implicit behavior for the first entry in `sys.path`.

The cases are:

1. Running `python3 Testing/Test_Programm.py`: `sys.path[0]` is `Testing/`, so when you import from `Testing.Programm`, it can't find any entry in `sys.path` with a `Testing` subdirectory and it gives up (same goes for `python3 Test_Programm.py`; no `Testing` within the script's folder)
2. Running `python3 -mTest_Programm` from the same directory also doesn't work; `sys.path[0]` is searching the current directory first, and again, there is no `Testing` subdirectory
3. `python3 -mTesting.Test_Programm` works because it's looking up the module to run, not directly executing the script, so `path[0]` remains the working directory, which *does* have a `Testing` subdirectory. It finds it, finds `Test_Programm.py` inside it, and when it runs, it *still* roots searches below `Testing` so imports from `Testing.Programm` work.